# Parse text file containing blog backup data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, text, file-handling

I have a .txt file containing Blog backup data. Format of data is as follows:

```
AUTHOR: A1
TITLE: title1…
STATUS: Publish
ALLOW COMMENTS: 1
CONVERT BREAKS: default
ALLOW PINGS: 0
PRIMARY CATEGORY: sample
CATEGORY: sample 2

DATE: 11/18/2010 09:36:00
-----
BODY:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetti industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
-----
EXTENDED BODY:

-----
EXCERPT:

-----
KEYWORDS:
Key1, Key2, key3
-----
```

I want the above content to be converted into an array of key-value pairs.
I have problem accessing multi-line values like BODY field or next-line like KEYWORDS.

```
$file_handle = fopen("show.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = array_map('trim', explode(':', $line_of_text, 2));

    //storing data in to arrray
    $result[$parts[0]] = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : ""; 
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far to accomplish your goal?

Comment: @RamRaider I have added the following code like
$file_handle = fopen("show.txt", "r");     
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = array_map('trim', explode(':', $line_of_text, 2));
 //storing data in to arrray
    $result[$parts[0]] = isset($parts[1]) ?$parts[1] : "";
}

Comment: normalize it, do first explode `----` and count then `:` in the parts, if there only one then take the hole line as entrie else explode again with `PHP_EOL` and then use the results each as entrie.

Comment: or what about `preg_match_all` with regex that  matches `uppercasewords with spaces` until `:` and all after that until `linebreak`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might find this helpful - it makes sense to prepare the data before attempting to make it into an array by removing junk characters, newlines etc

```
/* modify to suit path to your file */
$file='c:/temp2/blogdata.txt';
if( realpath($file) ){

    /* prepare the text by removing certain character sequences */
    $text=str_replace('-','',preg_replace('@:\r\n@',':',file_get_contents($file,FILE_TEXT)));

    /* create an array from the various lines */
    $a=explode( '|', preg_replace('@\r\n@', '|', $text));

    /* something to store the results in */
    $output=array();

    /* iterate through the array of data and add param/value to output */
    foreach($a as $pair){
        list($param,$value)=explode(':',$pair);
        if(!empty($param) &&!empty($value))$output[$param]=$value;
    }

    /* debug output */
    echo '<pre>',print_r($output,true),'</pre>';    
}
```

produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [AUTHOR] =>  A1
    [TITLE] =>  title1…
    [STATUS] =>  Publish
    [ALLOW COMMENTS] =>  1
    [CONVERT BREAKS] =>  default
    [ALLOW PINGS] =>  0
    [PRIMARY CATEGORY] =>  sample
    [CATEGORY] =>  sample 2
    [DATE] =>  11/18/2010 09
    [BODY] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetti industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    [KEYWORDS] => Key1, Key2, key3
)
```